# Using passworded public/private key to encrypt file in Java -- padding issues

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

***(I am restricted from using bouncy castle)***

I have a file that I want to encrypt, and then decrypt sometime later. I create a passworded keypair using the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out keypair.pem 1024
openssl rsa -in keypair.pem -outform DER -pubout -out public.der
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in keypair.pem -outform DER -out private.der
```

Then I go on to encrypt the file and also encrypt the password for the keys to the same 'encrypted' file. I'm having trouble with padding and I don't quite understand why. I understand the error, however I can't quite grasp where the exact problem lays as the code seems to be very delicate when manipulated.

Here is a snippet of both the methods I use for encrypting and decrypting the password:

```
private static byte[] passwordDecrypt(char[] password, byte[] ciphertext) {
    byte[] salt = new byte[8];
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(ciphertext);
    bais.read(salt, 0, 8);

    byte[] remainingCiphertext = new byte[ciphertext.length - 8];
    bais.read(remainingCiphertext, 0, ciphertext.length - 8);


    PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 1000, 64);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES");
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    PBEParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, ITERATIONS);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES");

    // Perform decryption.
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

    return cipher.doFinal(remainingCiphertext);
}

private static byte[] passwordEncrypt(char[] password, byte[] plaintext) {
    byte[] salt = new byte[8];
    Random random = new Random();
    random.nextBytes(salt);

    PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 1000, 64);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES");
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    PBEParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, ITERATIONS);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

    // Encrypt array
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);

    // Write out the salt, then the ciphertext and return it.
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.write(salt);
    b.write(ciphertext);
    return b.toByteArray();
}
```

The error points at the return statement of the passwordDecrypt function:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:913)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES1Core.doFinal(PBES1Core.java:416)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndTripleDESCipher.engineDoFinal(PBEWithMD5AndTripleDESCipher.java:326)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
at Crypto.passwordDecrypt(Crypto.java:471)
at Crypto.decryptFile(Crypto.java:399)
at test.main(test.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Can someone please push me in the right direction? Is there a way to neglect the illegal block size exception and make it decrypt successfully? I feel like I'm on the verge of making this work...

Comment: I don't usually use Java, but I do C# so much of this is familiar.  I have to be honest, I am not seeing anything obviously wrong.  How many bytes does it claim are in remainingCiphertext just before the decrypt attempt?  Ordinarily with .reads and .writes I would say to remember to .flush to clear the buffer, but this seems unlikely to be an issue with a method reading and writing an in-memory array.  Checking the byte length of remainingCiphertext for clues is the only thing that really comes to me, sorry.

Comment: WDS is right, you have to check the length of `remainingCiphertext` which is probably not a multiple of 8. You can still pad it with zeros.

Comment: Hi everyone. My apologies for the late reply -- my fault for posting right before a big weekend. I printed the **remainingCiphertext** and it is 669, which is indeed not divisible by 8. The further problem that I run into is that if I attempt to pad it with zeros until **remainingCiphertext** is divisible by 8(i added 3 to the length of remainingCiphertext making it 672), then I get the following error:

**BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded**

Which points at the same return statement. I'm trying different algo's besides PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I don't see any file handling, but if your stream handling is as shoddy as the one where you read out the bytes from the in memory stream, then you are in trouble. Please compare the ciphertext right after encryption to the one before decryption. *Never* ignore the return value of `read`, close your streams (using try-with-resources), etc.